# Could not resolve project :rncamerakit

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I install react-native-camera and got this issues.

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :rncamerakit.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No matching configuration of project :rncamerakit was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'react-native-camera' with value 'general', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
```

I tried to add this line but not work

```
 missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert the following lines in **android/app/build.gradle**

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general' <-- insert this line
  }
}
```

Comment: I did but not work

Comment: post your error text or screenshot here